# Trabalhar com dois cursores na mesma conexão

Tags: python-3.x

preciso fazer a leitura de duas tabelas no banco de dados de forma a compara-las posteriormente, o código que fiz esta dando erro, pois estou passando duas consultas na mesma conexão como poderia estar corrigindo isso? Obrigado.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=localhost;database=teste;uid=;pwd=")

cursor1 = conn.cursor()

cursor1.execute("select top 10 * from tab1")

cursor2 = conn.cursor()

cursor2.execute("select top 10 * from tab2")    

for row in cursor1:
   print(row)

for row in cursor2:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode corrigir isso sem infinitivo + gerúndio. Basta atribuir cada consulta a  uma variavel usando fetchAll() e posteriormente comparar as variaveis.